# React native communication with Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, protocols, communication

guys I have this very stupid question concerning react native and Firebase : how do they communicate between each other ? what's the protocol used ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Firebase SDK` (JavaScript, Java and Objective-C/Swift) use `web sockets` for communicating with the `Firebase database`, with fallback to long-polling.

The [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) is used with regular `HTTP` verbs (`GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` and `PATCH`) in a request/response. On top of that you can use `Firebase's REST streaming API` uses `SSE (server-sent events)` over `HTTP`.